# R package install fail on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: r, installation

After following [this](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/) successfully and getting Kick Things in, I get this on my Ubuntu 21.04

```
> sudo apt install --no-install-recommends r-cran-rstan
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-cran-v8 : Depends: libnode64 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

> sudo apt install --no-install-recommends r-cran-tidyverse
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-cran-stringi : Depends: libicu66 (>= 66.1-1~) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

BTW, I did the change to focal trick suggested for c2d4u.

Comment: They are the messages you get if you have not got c2d4u working. Is it definitely added ? Did you update (`apt-get update`) after adding it?

Comment: I had `https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/focal-cran40/` from something previous, I disabled it, did update, but still get the errors. What exactly should the URI be? I've got `http://ppa.launchpad.net/c2d4u.team/c2d4u4.0+/ubuntu/focal` I believe. Update gives `...Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/c2d4u.team/c2d4u4.0+/ubuntu focal InRelease...`

Comment: final entry from https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/c2d4u-ppa-release-file-for-ubuntu-21-04/24260/7 doesn't look promising

Comment: Jeez. What might be an alternative to get important packages?

Comment: Perhaps just using `install.packages` ; (I don't know why system dependencies would work though)